# TClientDataSet.AppendData cause "Trying to append data to a non-partial dataset" error

Tags: delphi

When execute the following code:

```
var S, D: TClientDataSet;
    P: TDataSetProvider;
    i: integer;
begin
  S := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  D := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  P := TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
  try
    S.FieldDefs.Add('F1', ftString, 20);
    S.FieldDefs.Add('F2', ftBcd,     2);
    S.FieldDefs.Add('F3', ftBoolean);
    S.CreateDataSet;
    S.AppendRecord(['Test 1', 1, True]);
    S.AppendRecord(['Test 2', 2, False]);
    S.First;
    S.MergeChangeLog;

    D.FieldDefs.Add('F1', ftString, 20); 
    D.FieldDefs.Add('F2', ftBcd,     2);
    D.FieldDefs.Add('F3', ftBoolean);
    D.CreateDataSet;

    P.DataSet := S;
    D.SetProvider(P);
    D.AppendData(P.GetRecords(-1, i, MetaDataOption), False);
  finally
    S.Free;
    D.Free;
    P.Free;
  end;
end;
```

An exception prompt "Trying to append data to a non-partial dataset".

However, the following code works:

```
var S, D: TClientDataSet;
    P: TDataSetProvider;
    i: integer;
begin
  S := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  D := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  P := TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
  try
    S.FieldDefs.Add('F1', ftString, 20);
    S.FieldDefs.Add('F2', ftBcd,     2);
    S.FieldDefs.Add('F3', ftBoolean);
    S.CreateDataSet;
    S.AppendRecord(['Test 1', 1, True]);
    S.AppendRecord(['Test 2', 2, False]);
    S.First;
    S.MergeChangeLog;

    // The 4 lines below that were in the first code sample are omitted here 
    //D.FieldDefs.Add('F1', ftString, 20); 
    //D.FieldDefs.Add('F2', ftBcd,     2);
    //D.FieldDefs.Add('F3', ftBoolean);
    //D.CreateDataSet;

    D.Data := S.Data;  // This line does not appear in the first code sample

    P.DataSet := S;
    D.SetProvider(P);
    D.AppendData(P.GetRecords(-1, i, MetaDataOption), False);
  finally
    S.Free;
    D.Free;
    P.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `D.CreateDataSet;` from your first code and you will be fine. It looks like the dataset does not accept any partial updates when `CreateDataSet` has been called.

```
procedure TForm7.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var S, D: TClientDataSet;
    P: TDataSetProvider;
    i: integer;
begin
  S := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  D := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  P := TDataSetProvider.Create(nil);
  try
    S.FieldDefs.Add('F1', ftString, 20);
    S.FieldDefs.Add('F2', ftBcd,     2);
    S.FieldDefs.Add('F3', ftBoolean);
    S.CreateDataSet;
    S.AppendRecord(['Test 1', 1, True]);
    S.AppendRecord(['Test 2', 2, False]);
    S.First;

    P.DataSet := S;
    D.SetProvider(P);
    D.AppendData(P.GetRecords(-1, i, MetaDataOption), False);
  finally
    S.Free;
    D.Free;
    P.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: My intention is to call AppendData into an active TClientDataSet (e.g.: var D).  Your proposal append data into an inactive dataset.

Comment: @ChauCheeYang After the *first* call to `AppendData` the dataset `D` is active and you can still continue to call `AppendData` on it to add more rows.

Comment: You are right.  However, the dataset D has initial data that is append manually using AppendRecord and that will prompt non partial dataset error.